# Use of "found" and "found to be"

Tags: grammar

I got a question about the use of "found" and "found to be"

May I ask if there is any grammar mistake in the following statement?

> During the test, the vulnerability was found fixed

Someone told me that it should be

> during the test, the vulnerability was found to be fixed

Actually, the background of this case is that I performed a test on a software and check if its vulnerability is fixed or not.

Comment: the problem with the first alternative is that, if the vulnerability was fixed, it presumably cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

Found+adjective is a form often used in expressions like "found guilty" or "found wanting" (probably because findings are the outcomes of inquiries, trials, inquests and audits).  "Found fixed" is therefore a *little* bit odd.

In your example 'determined to have been fixed/corrected' is more idiomatic and also removes some ambiguity about "fixed" (which also means unvarying).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of it's a legal thing to say. Very much like

> The patient was found deceased

It doesn't sound great though. And just like in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147124/found-missing-found-to-be-missing) question. I would actually prefer your suggestion. Or even:

> Was found to have been fixed.

Since this indicates someone applied the fix.

Comment: legal thing ??....

Comment: May I ask what tense this sentence "Was found to have been fixed" applied? Is it simple past tense?

Comment: Sorry, one more question. What is the difference in meaning between "found to have been fixed" and "found to be fixed"? Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelWong _found to have been fixed_ implies that someone fixed it. _found to be fixed_ can also be true if it wasn't broken in the first place.